# How to use triggers with multiple tables, are both tables included in the scope of the transaction and inserted table?

Tags: sql

I have a third party Contact database with contact data in two tables. So, I can't change the tables. The tables are contact1, contact2. The tables are updated on the same screen on the application. contact1 is the default table, and contact2 is used to add user defined columns.

The inserted table is only in scope for the the trigger when it executes. There are multiple users changing data on the network. How will I know if I am getting the correct data from the inserted table for contact1, when the update flag column is changed to Y on contact2?

The comment below was helpful "The inserted table in the trigger is relevant to the current transaction. While it may seem like multiple pieces of data are being edited all at the same time that isn't quite correct."

Comment: Not sure what your concern is here?

Comment: How will I know if I am getting the correct data from the inserted table for contact1, when the update flag column is changed to Y on contact2? There are multiple users changing data on the network. The contact1.status and contact2.updateflag are on the same screen in the application. When the contact2.updateflag is changed to Y, and I read the inserted table from contact1 how do I know it's the right inserted table. Is the Inserted table for conatct1 related to a user or machine?

Comment: It will ALWAYS be the right inserted table. The inserted table in the trigger is relevant to the current transaction. While it may seem like multiple pieces of data are being edited all at the same time that isn't quite correct. Any subsequent edits have to wait until the row is no longer locked by another edit.

Comment: Ok, so the transaction is the contact1, and contact2 tables that are both in edit modein the application screen. It sounds like the inserted table is for the transaction. So, does that mean the columns for contact1 are in scope for the trigger on contact2 since they are both in the transaction. So when the the trigger on contact2 executes, and tries to read the columns from contact1 and contact2 they will both have the new data.

Comment: No. Inserted is a virtual table that is available ONLY inside the trigger for that table. There are many levels of "it depends" in your question. I think it would be a good idea to share some code.

Comment: Btw. this design will not be the best you can do. In some cases both updates can lock each other and one transaction will be killed. Can't you make one application to master and one to slave? That's really painfull if multiple users can change one entry at the same time. Is the code of the applications maintained by you?

Comment: No, it's a third party application. We can only add triggers to it. We use a bridge database to store the updates in a que that are upserted to the ERP on an interval.